# Replace a string with a result from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string, code-snippets

How would I replace a string like: {snippet:1} with a MySQL result that uses the number (in this case 1) to select the row from a table that has 1 as its ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex for to separate out the integer from your string.

```
$string = '{snippet:1}';
preg_match('/\{snippet:(\d+)\}/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Output:

> 1

The `/`s are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends. The `\d` is any number and the `+` is a quantifier telling it that there can be one or more numbers. The `\`s are making the `{}`s literal.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cB9oN1/1

If this were JSON though...

```
$string = '{"snippet":"1"}';
$json_value = json_decode($string);
echo $json_value->snippet;
```

Output:

> 1

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot.